# Display none/block problems with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

In my webbpage I have to column with several articles in each column, see the HTML code below. I'm doing a responsive design. And when the viewport size is greater then 800 px, the text is visible with `display: block;`, but when the viewport is below 800 px, the text is hidden with `display: none;` in the CSS3 code. And when the text is hidden, a button with a plus sign are added in the same way with `display: block;` instead of the text. When the user click on the plus button, the text are visible again with jQuery `slideToggle`. So far so good.

But the problem that I have that is very confusing is that when I resize the browser window every thing works nice, until I click on one of the plus sign to view the hidden text and then the minus button to hide the text. But when I resize the browser upwards again, the text is hidden for good, but just for this article that I clicked on!? Am I clear enough? What could be the problem? I have been staring at the code for a long time, but I can't discover whats wrong. Anyone that could?

jQuery:

```
     $('div.plus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var article = $(this).parents('article');
    var extras = article.find('div.text').slideToggle('fast'); 
    var img = article.find('.plus img');
        if(img.attr('src') == "bilderGuide/bilderLayout/plus.png") {
        img.attr('src','bilderGuide/bilderLayout/minus.png');
        }
        else {
        img.attr('src','bilderGuide/bilderLayout/plus.png');
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<article>
<header>
<img src="image.jpg" alt=""/>
    <div class="articleContent">
        <div class="imageTextContainer">
        </div>
        <h2>H1</h2>
        <div class="text">
        <p>
        Text here
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="articleContentArrow"></div>
        <div class="plus"><a href="#"><img src="plus.png" /></a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: " But when I resize the browser upwards again, the text is hidden for good, but just for this article that I clicked on!?" So text is hidden, do you expect it to be visible when resizing? What is the behaviour you are expecting? I don't get it. Could you provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue?

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. What I ment was that when I resize the browser the text in the articles are hidden or displayed depending if the viewport size is below or above 800 px. But for the article that I clicked on, nothing happens, the text is hidden all the time while all other articles that are unclicked are hidden or visible when I resize the window.

Comment: My bad, i passed the part you were talking about viewport. See @Martijn's answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the slidetoggle, try toggling a class. That way the element never gets an inline-style, thus the problem isn't there.

jQuery sets the element `<elem style="display: none" />` when hiding it, inline styling overrules css styling, therefor your css can't re-open.

If you want the slide animation, use the css3 `transition: max-height 1s;` to go from 0 to something. Height doesnt work, nor does `max-heigth:auto;`. Maybe sometime in the future.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, but what do you mean by toggling a class? Some example code?

Comment: `article.find('div.text').toggleClass('someClassName'); `

Comment: OK, but isn't the text the .text class?

Comment: You give the element you want to toggle that `.toggleClass()`

Comment: Nothing works for me now! And I'm to tired! I have to continue tomorrow. Right now I don't get how the script could work at all with the var extras =... part!? That variable isn't used later in the code, or am I total wrong here!? :(